# AWS signing in user to cognito using serverless lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, serverless

I am trying to get a user to sign in to an Amazon Cognito User Pool using AWS API Gateway/ AWS Lambda in Node js. I have tried a lot of examples from the web, but none seems to work. I can hit the URL and come to the console log where it says "start 1" but then nothing beyond that. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  Here is my code:

```
'use strict';
const middy = require('middy');
const { cors } = require('middy/middlewares');
const config = require('../config');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const AmazonCognitoIdentity = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');
const CognitoUserPool = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool;
var AuthenticationDetails = AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails;
var CognitoUser = AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser;

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const request = require('request');
const jwkToPem = require('jwk-to-pem');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
global.fetch = require('node-fetch');


var poolData = config.poolData;
var userPool =
  new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);

const login = async (event, context) => {
  var body = JSON.parse(event.body);
  var email = body.userName;
  var password = body.password;

  console.log(body);

  var authenticationData = {
    Username: email,
    Password: password,
  };
  var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
  var userData = {
    Username: email,
    Pool: userPool
  };
  console.log('start 0');
  var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
  console.log("start 1");
  console.log(cognitoUser);

  try {
  cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
      onSuccess: (result) => {
        var accessToken = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
        console.log(result);
        console.log(accessToken);
        var idToken = result.idToken.jwtToken;
        console.log(idToken);
      },

      onFailure: (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        idToken = err;
        return;
      },
    });
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

const signin = middy(login)
  .use(cors()) // Adds CORS headers to responses

module.exports = { signin }
```

...and my serverless yml file is as follows:

```
service: resto # NOTE: update this with your service name

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: dev
  region: ap-southeast-2

functions:
  signup:
    handler: api/signup.auth
    memorySize: 128
    description: auth service
    events:
      - http: 
          path: api
          method: post
          cors: true
  signin:
    handler: api/signin.signin
    memorySize: 128
    description: signin service
    events:
      - http: 
          path: signin
          method: post
          cors: true
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

Sign-up works fine, but I am not sure why signing in does not work. Thanks!

Comment: The lambda code looks ok. You need to debug more. Start by just doing `console.log(result);` in success block and see if you get anything at all

Comment: I have done that but do not get anything.

Comment: Why don't you try the aws-sdk instead of the Identity JS SDK? Lambda would not require a deployment package for aws-sdk, and it would improve Cold Start times, thus improving the Lambda execution. Please look into the [InitiateAuth API call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html) for Cognito.

Comment: Thanks lightyagami, do you have a working example of this? AWS documentation is one of the worst I have seen.

Comment: This [code snippet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#initiateAuth-property) should be helpful. Be sure to import CognitoIdentityServiceProvider in the Node.js code as well.

Comment: Since you are  already initiating the aws-sdk, you could just create the CognitoIdentityServiceProvider object, and make relevant Native JS API calls.